# Unable to start Lubuntu on my netbook

Tags: lubuntu, login

i have an Asus netbook and after Windows started crashing terribly, I decided to find some ligther OS. I discovered Lubuntu 15.10-desktop. I managed to install it and now I have both Windows and Lubuntu (for what was left on the Windows, I did not want to lose it).

Anyway, to the problem. It was running fine for almost a year and then, all of sudden, when I wanted to turn it on, everything went ok except it wanted a password from me. It did not ask a password from me normally when I turnd my pc on, only when I woke it from hibernation or installing something. However, i typed the password and pressed enter. I expected to see a desktop, but instead, a black screen apeard for a second, then blicked some words (I could not manage to read them) and after it it returned me back to type my password like before. I tried it again, bu it goes in circles. Restart won´t help.

[image: Screen after entering password]
[image: Possible error messages]

Note that I am primary a Windows user.

Comment: Could you take a photo of the screen and add it to your question? Also please press Ctrl+Alt+F1, some error messages may be shown there. If yes, take a photo of them too. Then return to GUI with Ctrl+Alt+F7.

Comment: @Melebius I took those photos, please, take a look

Comment: There are no error messages, it looks like a normal boot without GUI… Something from https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2222849 may help. However, I cannot give you any specific advice as I have no experience with such a problem. I hope someone else will be able to help you…